# Scan all fields in dtos and find missing and extra fields by their Entities

Tags: java, junit, reflection

**I want to create a unit test that will use reflection to find all missing fields in dto that implement BaseDto by their persistence entities. This is what I did.**

```
@Slf4j
public class EntityAuditDtoTest {
    @Test
    public void find_MissingAndExtraFieldsThatUsedInAuditDtosByEntity_ReturnMissingAndExtraFields() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        // Arrange
        ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
        scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(AuditEntityType.class));

        // Find all classes annotated with @AuditEntityType in the package com.example.dto
        Set<BeanDefinition> auditDtoBeans = scanner.findCandidateComponents("com.example.dto");

        // Act
        for (BeanDefinition auditDtoBean : auditDtoBeans) {
            Class<?> auditDtoClass = Class.forName(auditDtoBean.getBeanClassName());

            // Make sure the DTO class implements BaseAuditDto
            if (!BaseAuditDto.class.isAssignableFrom(auditDtoClass)) {
                continue;
            }

            Class<?> entityClass = getEntityClassForDto(auditDtoClass);

            Field[] dtoFields = auditDtoClass.getDeclaredFields();
            Field[] entityFields = entityClass.getDeclaredFields();

            List<String> missingFields = Arrays.stream(entityFields).map(Field::getName)
                    .filter(field -> Arrays.stream(dtoFields).noneMatch(f -> f.getName().equals(field))).toList();

            if (!missingFields.isEmpty()) {
                log.error("Missing fields in DTO class: {} \nfor entity class: {} : {}", auditDtoClass.getName(),
                        entityClass.getName(), missingFields);
            }

            List<String> extraFields = Arrays.stream(dtoFields).map(Field::getName)
                    .filter(field -> Arrays.stream(entityFields).noneMatch(f -> f.getName().equals(field))).toList();

            if (!extraFields.isEmpty()) {
                log.error("Extra fields in DTO class: {} \nfor entity class: {} : {}", auditDtoClass.getName(),
                        entityClass.getName(), extraFields);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**But the problem is that the dto may have a field that is in the entity class, but the test will think that this is a missing field.**

For example:

Dto class: ContractAudit has customerId field (customerId). And ContractEntity has public CustomerEntity customer.
This is the same fields. But of course for test they are different. I don't understand how to ignore them. I also don't want to hardcode filter that skip all endings with 'id' prefix.

```
@Data
@AuditEntityType("Contract")
public class ContractAudit implements BaseAuditDto {
  private Long id;
  private String ref;
  private String status;
  private Long customerId;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "contract")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class ContractEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  @ToString.Include
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "ref", updatable = true)
  @ToString.Include
  private String ref;

  @Column(name = "status")
  @ToString.Include
  @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
  private ContractStatusEnum status;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
  public CustomerEntity customer;

  @Column(name = "deleted")
  @ToString.Include
  private boolean deleted;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "contract_id")
  private List<ContractDocumentEntity> documents;
}
```

Output:
Missing fields in DTO class: ContractAudit for entity class: ContractEntity : [customer, deleted, documents]

Extra fields in DTO class: ContractAudit for entity class: ContractEntity : [customerId]

I want to have missing fields: [deleted, documents]

If you have any other ideas on how to do this, I'd love to hear it. I am not asking for implementation. Suggestions only)

Answer (score 0):

Lol. I found solution for my case.
My previous approach was incorrect. Because it's impossible to find 'missing' and 'extra' fields by name correctly for every case. I decided to use:

```
assertThat(entityClass.getDeclaredFields()).hasSameSizeAs(auditDtoClass.getDeclaredFields());
```

So this code is checking if the entityClass and the DtoClass have the same number of fields (properties) declared. If not it fail test and print all fields from each classes. If anyone has better ideas I'll be happy to hear.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).